# Please explain the syntax in solr query fq = {!frange l=1 u=1}strdist(PR_EMP_ID_s, POSTN_PR_EMP_ROW_ID_s,edit)

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr-query-syntax

In the below syntax:

```
fq = {!frange l=1 u=1}strdist(PR_EMP_ID_s, POSTN_PR_EMP_ROW_ID_s,edit)
```

how to interpret this expression?

I know the basic fq working.

I have one query where I found this expression, but I am not able to interpret this syntax.

Comment: The filter calls `strdist` which returns the distance between the two strings. The `!frange` makes the selection that only a value of `1` is valid (lower bound 1, upper bound 1). If I read it correctly this should return any results with a single edit distance between `PR_EMP_ID_s` and the `POSTN_PR_EMP_ROW_ID_s` fields.

Comment: Can you please explain, the meaning of distance between two strings.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance